# Angular 2 error NullInjectorError: No provider for Http

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-providers

I am trying to read a json github service and I am getting an error     NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!

I already to add providers all over the code but it is not working I dont know what is causing the error but know where it is happening i need some who can help to understand what is causing this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, Http, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@NgModule({

    imports: [     
          BrowserModule,
          HttpModule,
          JsonpModule,

        ]

  }) 

  @Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
  })
 export class GithubService{
       constructor(private http:Http){

       }

       getUser(){
         const searchText ="js";
         const url = "http://api.github.com/search/users?q="+searchText;  
         this.http.get(url).subscribe(
           res=> {
             const data=res.json();
             console.log(data);
             return data;
           }
         )
       }
   }
```

Error I am getting:

```
AppComponent.html:7 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[GithubService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[GithubService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
```

Comment: where did you import your `HttpModule`?

Answer (score 8):

**Update: Angular v6+**
**From older versions (Angular v2 - v5): HttpModule is now deprecated and you need to replace it with HttpClientModule or else you will get the error too.**

In your **app.module.ts** file change these

1. import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
2. Then update the modules **imports[ ]** array **HttpClientModule**

   ```
      @NgModule({
           imports: [
               BrowserModule,
               FormsModule, // if used
               HttpClientModule,
           ],
           declarations: [ AppComponent ],
           bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
       })
   ```

Comment: I cant simply update to A6 because the site is buildted on A2

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below 2 steps,

Go to app.moudle.ts

1. Add javascript import

   ```
   import { HttpModule, Http, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
   ```
2. Add @ngModule Angular import

   ```
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     HttpModule
   ],
   ```

Comment: it did not work I am getting the same error after adding the imports

Comment: Try importing your modules- HttpModule and others in app.module.ts